# Asp.net setting some context for a Custom UITypeEditor from parent form at Design Time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, design-time, uitypeeditor

Trying to craft a way for our designers to create custom asp.net webforms for our customers.  The basic idea is that we have a general set of fields that can be saved, with each customer using a subset of those fields, each customer may have it's own names for similar concepts (ie one customer may use 'patient' and another 'customer').  Staying in customer context will help the designers build the correct form to meet the customers needs.

Now to do this I need to get as much as I can into the design experience as possible.  I have a set of custom controls that derive from base controls like asp:TextBox and implements an interface to allows me to iterate over the controls and insert values from a data store, or fetch values to persist (Done).  All of these controls need to be bound to a data point in my record object.  I have a metadata system set up to allow the binding, but where I am running into trouble is in getting the list of available fields into a UITypeEditor.  Namely, I haven't figured out how to (at design time) set the customer context on the form, and then access and use that value on each controls custom property editor (also at design time).  Is this possible?  Am I looking at this problem the wrong way?  A form always has 1 and only one customer context.  So in my forms project, each form will have a different customer id set to it.

As a second question how can I debug these editors?  There is an expectation of web context in the editors, but there is no asp.net property grid.  and even if there was, the editors are winforms components that wouldn't run in a browser.

I can include the code I currently have if it simplifies the problem, but even a simplified example is a half dozen classes.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved these issues, posting here in case a general solution can be useful to anyone in the future.

I was able to get around this problem a bit by going the other way.  My parent Page iterates over it's controls, and sets the CustomerId on all the controls that implement a specific interface.

As for debugging.  Some refactoring got me to a place where I can easily swap out the webforms specific parts of  my implementation for testing.